# Save file dialog in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, savefiledialog

How to create save file dialog in MVC application?
I couldn't find any example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using the `Content-Disposition` header to attachment when returning the file to download:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    return File(@"c:\work\report.pdf", "application/pdf", "reoprt.pdf");
}
```

Or if the file to download is dynamically generated:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    byte[] pdf = ... get the contents of the report
    return File(pdf, "application/pdf", "reoprt.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Are your return statements correct? Don't you need to call a method?

Comment: I was only able to get this to work using the return type FileResult `public FileResult Download()`.  This is probably due to web browser security changes since '11.