# SaveFileDialog doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net

i'm developing an action which create an excel file and then, open a SaveFileDialog allowing clients to save it in their computer.

The problem is that in Local, the SaveFileDialog works but appears behind my browser window, which is a problem...

And then, when I publish it in my server, the SaveFileDialog do totally not work.
It makes about 2 days I'm reading some other topics about that here on Stackoverflow but I still haven't found the right answer...

(Sorry about my English mistakes, i'm french).
Here is my code :

```
String path = string.Empty;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
bool canExport = false;

Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range)ws.get_Range("A1", "K1");
/** Excel File completion **/
/** ... **/
/** ... **/
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.InitialDirectory = Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal.ToString();
    sfd.Filter = "Classeur Excel 2010 (*.xls)|*.xls";

    if (STAShowDialog(sfd) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        path = sfd.FileName;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                canExport = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Impossible d'écrire par-dessus ce fichier.");
                canExport = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            canExport = true;
        }
    }

    SaveExcelFile(canExport, wb, path, app, ws, misValue);
    return View();
```

And now my functions :

```
public void SaveExcelFile(bool canExport, Excel.Workbook wb, String path, Excel.Application app, Excel.Worksheet ws, object misValue)
{
    if (canExport)
    {
        try
        {
            wb.SaveAs(path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
                          Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
                          XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);


            wb.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            app.Quit();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problème durant l'exportation\r\n Code erreur #EX01");
        }
    }

    releaseObject(ws);
    releaseObject(wb);
    releaseObject(app);
}

private DialogResult STAShowDialog(FileDialog dialog)
{
    DialogState state = new DialogState();
    state.dialog = dialog;
    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(state.ThreadProcShowDialog) { IsBackground = true, Name = "threadExport", Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.AboveNormal };
    t.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
    t.Join();
    return state.result;
}
```

Comment: This is a web application yes?

Comment: You are not thinking as a Web Developer. Don't use dialog in a web application, bad idea. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816727/save-file-dialog-in-mvc

Comment: and where is `ThreadProcShowDialog`? And your threading certainly looks weird. Typically you simply show such dialogs on the main thread.

Comment: The problem is that my file isn't saved on the server because Excel isn't install on it. So I need a way to allow the download without giving an url... Just with the Woorkbook object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be able to show a Save File dialog using `SaveFileDialog` from a web server to a local computer. The only way you can trigger a Save File Dialog via the browser is to link the user to the file on the Web Server or to serve a page with the correct MIME Type. This is usually accomplished using an [HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

The Save File Dialog is opening on the server itself...

Example:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %> 

using System; 
using System.Web; 

public class Handler : IHttpHandler { 

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) { 

        HttpResponse r = context.Response; 
        r.ContentType = "image/png"; 
        // 
        // Write the requested image 
        // 
        string file = context.Request.QueryString["file"]; 

// Get Data From Database. And write file. 
        if (file == "logo") 
        { 
            r.WriteFile("Logo1.png"); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            r.WriteFile("Flower1.png"); 
        } 
    } 

    public bool IsReusable { 
        get { 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Source: [Http Handler ASP.NET Sample Request](http://forums.asp.net/t/1753103.aspx/1)

Comment: The problem is that my file isn't saved on the server because Excel isn't install on it. So I need a way to allow the download without giving an url... Just with the Woorkbook object

Comment: @fitz_lucassen I don't understand what you mean. Where is the code executing and what is the *expected* results? What is the topology as well (Web Server, File Server, etc.)? Add as much detail in the question as is feasible and I'll attempt to clarify my answer.

Comment: Ok I'll try to clarify. I'm in .NET MVC 3 and it's a web server (IIS). I have a link on my website. When a client click on it, he is redirected to an action called "ExcelList" for instance. The code of this action is in my first message above. I create an Excel file (thanks to the interop framework) and then I just want (without saving it on the server) the action downloading the file just created. Do you want anymore information ?

Comment: @fitz_lucassen In that case, you need to use code similar to my answer to create an HttpHandler that would serve this file. You don't need to save the file first you can output the excel file to a MemoryStream and then serve that MemorySteam using your HttpHandler.

Comment: yeah I saw that but unfortunately it seems that I haven't the function "SaveToStream"... Do you how to save a Workbook object into stream or bytes ?